# Hot Loader not working

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I am trying to use Hot Loader. I have installed Hot Loader and followed all the steps from the documentation http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/. I then give "npm start" command to the terminal. But terminal throws an error. I am not able to see the changes I make in the component getting reflected in browser.

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: './src',
        port: 3000
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // "only" prevents reload on syntax errors
        './dev/js/index.js' // Your appʼs entry point
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot','babel'],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
output: {
        path: 'src',
        filename: 'js/bundle.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Script part of Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

server.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');
var port = 3000;
var compiler = webpack(config);

new webpackDevServer(compiler, {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot:true,
    stats:{colors:true}
}).listen(port, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('listening at localhost' + port);
});
```

[image: Terminal output]
[image: Project Structure]

Few quetions
1. Is my server.js file is fine.
2. Have I included everything correctly in scripts in package.json.
3. Is "npm start" a command to launch hot loader.
4. Even after getting error after "npm start", I can launch my application 
   in the browser by clicking the chrome icon. What is the reason.
5. What should I change in these files to get a working hot loader.

[image: Browser window]

Comment: When you refer to files or directories in `webpack.config.js`, you need to use absolute paths.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Which part of the code is wrong in it and what it should be?

Comment: Start by making the paths in `output` and `entry` absolute. For example, `path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')` (for `output.path`).

Comment: @robertklep this worked. Terminal says "webpack bundle is now valid". But still when I click the chrome icon to launch the app I get's  launched with the previous state and changes are not reflecting on the go. Seems like I am not launching it the right way. What should I do?

Comment: Perhaps you need to reload once to load the updated code. After that, any changes that you make should be reflected in the browser, provided that you keep the browser window open.

Comment: Reloading didn't work. I am attaching the image of browser window because when I launch the application (from chrome icon) it gets open in "localhost:63342" and In my webpack I have given port:3000. Why this is happening. Kindly look at the image I am attaching in my ques.

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, it may be because of the IDE that you're using.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help. I am still struggling with it.